# Shall we need to add volatile to the variables when using java ReentrantLock?

Tags: java, multithreading

I see the code below from **[Java8 Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)**,and I have a question:

Since the method `put()` and `take()` might be invoked by multiple thread at the same time,shall we need to add **volatile** to the variables in order to get the right value?

For example:
For the array `items`,if two threads invoke `put()` to add element to it,and another thread invoke `take()` to get element from it,will there be have some scenario that the `take()` is not get the latest data from the main memory?
How do the program can make sure the thread invoke `take()` always get the right size of `items`?

```
 class BoundedBuffer {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   //shall we need to add volatile to the variables below
   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length)
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x;
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0)
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr];
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: making `final Object[] items` volatile makes no sense. To create an array of "volatile" values, you need to use `AtomicReferenceArray`. But, here, `ReentrantLock#lock` return is point of synchronization, making mentioned variables "guarded" by this lock, so answer is - no, you don't need to make them volatile.

Comment: @AlexSalauyou The code is I copied from Oracle java api as I mentioned in my question,according to your comment and my understanding:`final` is redundant,if the method has a lock,then `volatile` is also redundant,if there is no lock,then `volatile` is necessary,is that right?

Comment: yes, except of making array volatile doesn't make sense if you only operate contents of array (making array volatile does not make its items behave like volatile).

Answer (score 2):

Keywords like `volatile` are shallow.  Just like `final`, `static`, `private` apply to when the reference to the array is altered, changing the **contents** of the array is not covered.

e.g. instead of

```
Object[] array;

array[0] = "hello";
```

If you change to `final`

```
final Object[] array;

array[0] = "hello"; // I can still alter the array referrenced
```

If you change to `volatile`

```
volatile Object[] array;

array = new Object[1]; // a write barrier is added as I wrote to array
array[0] = "hello"; // I didn't change the array reference so no write barrier
```

> Since the method put() and take() might be invoked by multiple thread at the same time,shall we need to add volatile to the variables in order to get the right value?

Using the `ReeentrantLock` correctly will add the read/write barriers you need.

Comment: In OP's code all operations upon array are performed between `lock` and `unlock` of the same `Lock`, thus happen-before relationship is followed, and read are actual states of variables, even non-volatile.

Comment: So if we remove `final` keyword,shall we still do not need `volatile`?